# Category vs Tag

Tags: categories, tags, category

Is there a fundamental difference between a Craft Category and a Tag?  I originally set up a site using Tags before the Category feature was available and now I'm adding a new section and trying to figure out which I should use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably did not yet come across this site:

["Categories and Tags – Everything in its right place."](https://craftcms.com/features/all#categories-and-tags)

Craft's explanation about Categories:

> You can set up Category Groups for managing different taxonomies within Craft, and then apply categories to other elements using a Categories field.

And what they have to say about Tags:

> Craft has built-in folksonomy support as well, with tags. You can set up multiple Tag Groups, and each group will have its own unique set of tags. Create tags on the fly from Tags fields.

Comment: The Craft site must have updated the docs since the last time I reviewed the Categories and Tags docs.  Sorry about that!  Thank you for the link.

Comment: Yes, the videos are new and many articles got updated.

Answer (score 2):

from what i know Category is can have a structure

ex:

Cat 1

-- Cat 11

Cat 2

Cat 3

-- Cat 33

---- Cat 333

Tag is multiple. good for filter elements